# Loading spinner typeaheadjs bloodhound tagsinput

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js, bloodhound, bootstrap-tags-input

I've setup an autocomplete search form with bloodhound and tagsinput.

It works well in remote but suggestions take about 1 or 2 seconds to show with Wordpress API.

I'd like to add a loading spinner to the input. That way it will be clear for people that they have to wait for suggestions to load.

I'm aware of this post https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/166 but it's only about typeaheadjs and not tagsinput. And to be honest, I don't understand very well the purpose of typeaheadjs when I use bloodhound and tagsinput.

I use the 2 js files: typeahead.bundle.js and bootstrap-tagsinput.js

Here is my working code (without the spinner):

```
var transform_terms = function( terms ) {
            return $.map( terms, function( term ) {
                return {
                    id: term.id,
                    name: term.name,
                    count: term.count
                };
            } );
        };

        var localisations = new Bloodhound( {
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace( [ 'name', 'id' ] ),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            identify: function( term ) {
                return {
                    label: term.name,
                    value: term.id,
                };
            },
            sufficient: 5,              
            remote: {
                url: '/wp-json/wp/v2/localisation?_fields=name,id&orderby=count&order=desc&hide_empty=false&search=%QUERY',
                wildcard: '%QUERY',
                transform: transform_terms
            },
            indexRemote: true
        } );
        localisations.initialize();


        $('#localisation').tagsinput({
            itemValue: 'id',
            itemText: 'name',
            maxTags: 5,
            confirmKeys: [13, 9],
            typeaheadjs: {
                name: 'localisations',
                displayKey: 'name',
                source: localisations.ttAdapter()
            }
        });
```

Can anyone help me to add a spinner during the query process?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this very good post https://digitalfortress.tech/tutorial/smart-search-using-twitter-typeahead-bloodhound/, I've found a solution that seems reliable. But I have to say that using Bootstrap Typeahead is not obvious and documentation is poor...

Here is my new working code:

```
var transform_terms = function( terms ) {
            return $.map( terms, function( term ) {
                return {
                    id: term.id,
                    name: term.name,
                    count: term.count
                };
            } );
        };

        var localisations = new Bloodhound( {
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace( [ 'name', 'id' ] ),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            identify: function( term ) {
                return {
                    label: term.name,
                    value: term.id,
                };
            },
            sufficient: 5,

            remote: {
                url: '/wp-json/wp/v2/localisation?_fields=name,id&orderby=count&order=desc&hide_empty=false&search=',
                prepare: function (query, settings) {
                    console.log('load');
                    $("#search-loader").fadeIn();
                    settings.url = this.url + query;
                    return settings;
                },
                filter: function (data) {
                    console.log('finish');
                    $("#search-loader").fadeOut();
                    return data;
                }
            },
            identify: function (response) {
                return response.name;
            },
            indexRemote: true
        } );
        localisations.initialize();


        $('#localisation').tagsinput({
            itemValue: 'id',
            itemText: 'name',
            maxTags: 5,
            confirmKeys: [13, 9],
            typeaheadjs: [{
                    highlight: true
                },{
                    name: 'localisations',
                    displayKey: 'name',
                    source: localisations.ttAdapter()
                }]
        });
```